# file_get_contents displays nothing when used with $_GET

Tags: php, get, file-get-contents

I'm having a problem when using file_get_contents combined with $_GET. For example, I'm trying to load the following page using file_get_contents:

https://bing.com/?q=how+to+tie+a+tie

If I were to load it like this, the page loads fine:

**http://localhost/load1.php**

```
<?
echo file_get_contents("https://bing.com/?q=how+to+tie+a+tie");
?>
```

However, when I load it like this, I'm having problems:

**http://localhost/load2.php?url=https://bing.com/?q=how+to+tie+a+tie**

```
<?
$enteredurl = $_GET["url"];
$page = file_get_contents($enteredurl);
echo $page;
?>
```

When I load using the second method, I get a blank page. Checking the page source returns nothing. When I echo $enteredurl I get "https://bing.com/?q=how to tie a tie". It seems that the "+" signs are gone.

Furthermore, loading **http://localhost/load2.php?url=https://bing.com/?q=how** works fine. The webpage shows up.

Anyone know what could be causing the problem?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Trying to use urlencode() to achieve this. I have a standard form with input and submit fields:

```
<form name="search" action="load2.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="search" />
<input type="submit" value="Go!" />
</form>
```

Then to update load2.php URL:

```
<?
$enteredurl = $_GET["url"];
$search = urlencode($_POST["search"]);
if(!empty($search)) {
echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location="load2.php?url=https://bing.com/?q='.$search.'";</script>';
}
?>
```

Somewhere here the code is broken. $enteredurl still returns the same value as before. (https://bing.com/?q=how to tie a tie)

Comment: This is a bad, bad idea from a security standpoint. `file_get_contents()` works on local files, not just URLs. What if `$enteredurl` is `/etc/passwd` or some other important file? How are you going to prevent users from viewing any file on your system?

Comment: Yes, that has been a problem I've been considering. Does anyone know of any way to protect against this security flaw?

Comment: Basically, just make sure `$enteredurl` starts with `http://` or `https://` and disallow anything else.

Comment: Yep, that's what I was thinking. I'll be sure to implement that. Thanks :)

Comment: No problem. I deleted my earlier comment, I see that you can open URLs.

Comment: @CharlesTian try `urlencode()`.

Comment: @MrCode I've tried that before, but it didn't change anything. You mean like `$enteredurl = urlencode($_GET["url"])` right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to encode your parameters properly `http://localhost/load2.php?url=https://bing.com/?q=how+to+tie+a+tie` should be `http://localhost/load2.php?urlhttps%3A%2F%2Fbing.com%2F%3Fq%3Dhow%2Bto%2Btie%2Ba%2Btie`. you can use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) in JavaScript to do this or [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) in php.

---

```
<?
$enteredurl = $_GET["url"];
$search = urlencode($_POST["search"]);
if(!empty($search)) {
    $url = urlencode('https://bing.com/?q='.$search)
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location="load2.php?url='.$url.'";</script>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working. Do you know of any way to do this using PHP instead of Javascript?

Comment: I've modified my code like this: `$get = $_GET["url"];
$enteredurl = urlencode($get); $page = file_get_contents($enteredurl); echo $page;` but I'm still getting the same blank page as the result. Also, `echo $get;` and `echo $enteredurl;` return the same thing. Can you help?

Comment: @CharlesTian you need to encode the url at the source, i.e. the requester has to encode the url.

Comment: @CharlesTian however its done it has to be done at the source. How is the request to `load2.php` being made?

Comment: I'm using a simple input box with name "inputurl" and `$_POST["inputurl"]`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Can you explain why this works instead of my previous code? Much appreciated :)

Comment: @CharlesTian all parameters in a url has to be properly encoded. `$search = urlencode($_POST["search"]);` encodes the bing search parameters and `urlencode('https://bing.com/?q='.$search)` encodes `load2.php` url parameter.